# Is there a software that allows cutting while recording?

Tags: editing, cutting

While recording a lecture, there are some pauses that are longer than 2 seconds or "ums" and "errs" that I  would like to remove but have the sound continue recording. Purely to save time.

At the moment I am using Sound Forge 11 (Sony build)

Would there be another software that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) is a classic, freely available, open source DAW that should work for recording lectures. When I record podcasts, I'll occasionally want to pause mid-recording to collect my thoughts or look at notes. I use the 'p' keyboard shortcut to toggle pausing and continuing recording.

Alternately, you could record the entire lecture, and then use the build-in effects to remove silences. Effect > Truncate silence. The settings for that effect will allow you to set a threshold and choose whether to shorten to a fixed length for each silence, or compress the silence to speed things up. The [documentation](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/truncate_silence.html) is very good.